# Why does BadRequest(ModelState) return Status Code 500?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api controller turning return `BadRequest(ModelState)` if it fails the `ModelSatate.IsValid` check like so.

```
if(ModelState.IsValid) {
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

But why is the response code a 500 and not 400?  If I just return `BadRequest()` without the ModelState, I get a 400.

```
if(ModelState.IsValid) {
    return BadRequest();
}
```

Comment: 500 is an internal server error, are you sure that your app doesn't crashes on the second case?

Comment: Yes. That is how I noticed it was a 400 vs 500 when I pass in the ModelState.

Comment: sorry, but "yes" means that your app crashes or that your app doesn't crashes? :D

Comment: It must be an exception in your code, by the docs, "BadRequest(ModelStateDictionary) Creates an InvalidModelStateResult with the specified model state.". If you go to the git for the mvc you can see how it creates that class, and that class indeed generates a 400 error (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a78f77afde003c4a3fcf5dd7b6dc13dd9c85f825/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/InvalidModelStateResult.cs)